# Getting error "Invalid switch "e" when running dotCover

Tags: code-coverage, dotcover

I am running dotCover from our TFS2015 build using a Windows batch file as follows:

*E:\JetBrains\Installations\dotCover05\dotCover.exe analyse coverage.xml*

However I am getting an error **"Invalid switch "e"**

[image]

We are running the latest version of dotCover (downloaded only yesterday) on our build server. We are also running VS 2015 Community Edition on the build server (so as not to consume a licence on our build server).

The coverage.xml file contains the following entries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
  <TargetExecutable>E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\bin\Release\CoreLibraryTests.dll</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir>E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\bin\Release\</TargetWorkingDir>
  <Output>output.xml</Output>
</AnalyseParams>
```

When I invoke MSTest.exe directly from the command line it works correctly i.e.

*"E:\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:CoreLibraryTests\bin\Release\CoreLibraryTests.dll*

So the issue appears to be how dotCover is launching MSTest.exe with the parameters supplied in the coverage.xml file

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix this after a bit of trial and error.

In my coverage.xml file I added /testcontainer to the <TargetArgument /> node as follows.

```
<TargetArguments>/testcontainer:E:\TfsData\Build\_work\DEV\CoreLibraryTests\bin\Release\CoreLibraryTests.dll</TargetArguments>
```

Everything now works correctly.